# How do I create an "Activate" and a "Deactivate" button in C++

Tags: c++, windows

Basically what I want my coded to do is perform a few lines of code when the "Activate" button is pressed.  That part is easy.  The hard part is making the lines execute over and over until the "Deactivate" button is pressed.

```
switch (message)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindow(
            TEXT("button"),TEXT("Activate"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            25,
            30,
            100,
            50,
            hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL
            );
        CreateWindow(
            TEXT("button"),TEXT("Deactivate"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            150,
            30,
            100,
            50,
            hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL
            );
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if(LOWORD(wParam) == 1)
        {
            /*DO STUFF*/
        }
        if(LOWORD(wParam) == 2)
        {
            /*STOP DOING STUFF*/
        }
        break;
}
```

I tried creating a `while(i == true)` but that didn't work:

```
bool i = false;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if(LOWORD(wParam) == 1)
        {
            i = true;

            while(i == true)
            {
                /*DO STUFF*/
            }
    }
    if(LOWORD(wParam) == 2)
    {
        i = false;
    }
    break;
```

If I could get help with with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

**---EDIT---**

I probably should have told you what `/*DO STUFF*/` was.  I am making a custom macro clicker.  I have a working one already, but i am unhappy with it because it uses `cout <<` as a menu.  On that version, I use this code:

```
while(1)
{
    if(GetKeyState(0x43) & 0x8000) /*This if() statement auto clicks whenever "C" is held*/
    {
        usleep(13625);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to activate and deactivate this while(1) statement?

Comment: Is this "/*DO STUFF*/" something accessing the GUI?

Comment: No.  I probably should have mentioned what I am using this program for.  I am creating a custom macro clicker.  I have a working one already, but im not happy with it because it uses `cout <<` as a menu.  Ill edit the post and say what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What is the behavior of your current code?
Do you run an infinite loop inside your while loop, and `i` is never set to false?

Comment: Your mouse events are probably interfering with your button click on a different listening thread.